# Mexican "Área Geoestadistica Básica" OSM admin level

Tags: openstreetmap, administrative-boundaries, mexico

I found shapefiles that split urban areas in Mexico into distinctions called Área Geoestadistica Básica (AGEB) from Mexico's geographic information site, [INEGI](http://www.inegi.org.mx/geo/contenidos/geoestadistica/M_Geoestadistico.aspx)

This is what the divisions of Mexico city look like:
[image]

The link to download the shapefiles is [here](http://mapserver.inegi.org.mx/MGN/mgau2013v6_0.zip) (32 mb)

I know the following mapping of geographic distinctions exists within Open StreetMap in Mexico:
[image] (from wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WikiProject_Mexico)

- I was wondering if anyone knows if there is any OSM mapping for these Basic Geostatistical areas?
- If not, are they just like census tracts/blocks in the US that serve purposes for information gathering, but are not used for administrative purposes?

My apologies if this is more of a basic translation questions - I've looked around for anything in English describing what they are and was wondering if anyone had any more specific information about the nature of these divisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find anything about OSM mapping for AGB's however I found [this PowerPoint](http://www.uaemex.mx/REBICS/docs/publica_memorias/047_pres_t_herramINEGI_VNC.pdf) that explains what these AGB's are, it states:

[image]

Google translates this to:

> ```
>     The Geostatistical Framework, is a system designed by INEGI to
> reference the statistical information generated by the different census projects or surveys,
> with appropriate geographic locations.
> The geostatistical framework consists of three geographical levels,
> whose base is attached as close possible to the political-administrative boundaries of the entities
> states, municipalities and localities that it integrates
> ```

The next slide then describes AGB's as:
[image]
Google translation:

> Basic Geostatistical Area (BGA) - Corresponding to a part of a
> Municipality, Town or Delegation Policy. In these areas there are two
> types: Urban and Rural.

So I would think they would be similar to census blocks in that they are used when referencing census projects or surveys.

Comment: Basically yes, exact same principle these are Census Blocks for Mexico

Answer (score 1):

The AGEB is part of the National Geostatistical Framework (abbreviated as MGN in Spanish) it's not an official administrative level so you're right in that it's not used for administrative purposes but for statistical and census geo-referencing purposes, however, it's so heavily used for research that it would make sense to have the MGN levels mapped to OSM admin levels. Additionally according to the INEGI, all government geographic data must be released using the keys of the MGN as a geo-referencing framework, which makes it almost impossible to be replaced by any other geo-referencing framework anytime soon.

Please note that although the AGEB is not an administrative level, the other two levels above it certainly are, those are named AGEE and AGEM and also form part of the MGN.

You can find more detailed information about the MGN in the OSM Wiki, at [MGN OSM INEGI](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Marco_Geoestad%C3%ADstico_Nacional_(MGN))

In the same wiki it's mentioned that there's a plan to import the MGN dataset to OSM, which means that it would be possible that the OSM admin levels will be at some point in the future including the administrative levels as defined in the MGN (Which may include the AGEB).